# Is there a shorter way to show the union of many sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $\space H_n \space$ be a set such that:

$$H_{n} = \{ h^2\in \mathbb{N} : n \leq h \leq n^2  \}$$

Where of course $\space n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now if I wanted to specify the union of (for example) $\space H_1 \space$ and $\space H_2 \space$, I could simply write:

$$H_{1} \cup H_{2}$$

But what if I wanted to specify the union of all sets from $\space H_1 \space$ to $\space H_{50} \space$.

Is there any shorter way of writing  this?

Kind of like how we use the sigma notation to express sums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cap$ is for intersection. In any case, the answer is $\cup_{n=1}^{50}H_n$ or $\bigcup_{n=1}^{50}H_n$ if you prefer a bigger union symbol.

Comment: Ahh my bad, I always get the names confused...and thank you, I assuemed it would be something like that :)